# Spline / canvas re-render when switch between pages in Nextjs / ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-canvas, spline

i have 3d design Spline, and i want to export my Spline to my website, the Spline is work well in my website, But the problem is when i switch the page from Home page to About page, the Spline is re-rendering.

here's the screenshots:

[From Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nt1U.png)

[To About page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5cSq.png)

[Back to Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nGuf.png)

here's the detail of code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/broken-rain-gynch3?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A21%2C32

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue , but for a work-around what i did was rendered that spline component in app.js , and hide spline container using css , ie display : none or block [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0btUI.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13138364)